# Handling MySQL transactions without mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I'm working on a university project at the moment and they've informed me that they won't support `mysqli` in their hosting environment.

While this seems a backwards decision to me, it's what I'm dealing with. Is there a way to handle transactions in MySQL using the old `mysql` library?

We have a volatile process involving student data that really needs transaction handling. The process was written by students years ago and is naturally prone to errors. All of it was written with `mysql` functions until I converted them to `mysqli`. We don't have time or budget to refactor the whole thing, so I just need a way to get transactions working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you do not want to go back to the old `mysql` as it is being taken out of PHP for a reason.

Look into `PDO`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And you will soon find yourself completely falling in love with this one. It exceeds `mysql` and `mysqli` by far, and your university will be happy to see this coming in

Comment: I completely agree with this, but I don't have a choice in the technologies available.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions in mysql are handled by means of simple SQL commands like `START TRANSACTION` and such. You are allowed to issue these commands from client using whatever API you like.

Comment: Before I converted to `mysqli`, I attempted to use these commands. However, they were not honored on the database side and performing a rollback had no effect. Is there a special trick to doing this in PHP?

Comment: No, there are none. Everything as straight and simple as in console